# How to have the children affect the parent in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a situation where I have something like this:

```
<DropDown>
  <p>Select an option:</p>
  <button onClick={() => console.log("opt 1")}>Option 1</button>
  <button onClick={() => console.log("opt 1")}>Option 2</button>
</DropDown>
```

The `DropDown` component is one that I wrote, that renders `this.props.children` in a drop-down fashion. The DropDown has an `onClick` call that makes it close.

`DropDown` looks something like this (simplified):

```
class DropDown extends Component {
  state = {
    open: false
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={`drop-down ${this.state.open ? "open" : "closed"}`}>
        <div className="closed-version">
          <div className="header" onClick={this.open}>
            <div className="header-contents">Click here to select an option</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="open-version">
          <div className="content" onClick={this.closeWithoutSelection}>
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  open = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true }, () => {
      if (this.props.onOpen) {
        this.props.onOpen();
      }
    });
  };

  closeWithoutSelection = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false }, () => {
      if (this.props.onCloseWithoutSelection) {
        this.props.onCloseWithoutSelection();
      }
    });
  };
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that I want to do something different to the DropDown whether it was closed selecting an option or not. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: You can pass function as props and manage the state in parent

Comment: Each button can have an id an you do event => this.props.handleClick(event.target.id) on onClick

Comment: @QuentinC: I'm trying not to extract the state of whether the drop down is open or not from the dropbox itself, as it would tightly couple dropbox to the parent in an error-prone way.

Comment: You don't need to tightly couple anything in React. render props is just one solution which I highly recommend. Moving forward, hooks is probably a neater solution. I can amend my answer to include hooks as well if you're using react 16.8 +

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `DropDown` component you have some state and you are probably rendering your children like this:

```
this.props.children
```

Instead you can use [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) to pass state, methods or anything else down to your children without having to handle it outside of the DropDown component at the parent level.

```
class DropDown extends Component {
  // constructor / state, methods...

  yourSpecialMethod(item) {
    // do your special thing here
  }

  render() {
    // pass state or methods down to children!
    return this.props.children(yourSpecialMethod)
  }
}
```

Then modify your render slightly:

```
<DropDown>
  {handleSpecialMethod =>
    <>
      <p>Select an option:</p>
      <button onClick={() => handleSpecialMethod("opt 1")}>Option 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => handleSpecialMethod("opt 1")}>Option 2</button>
    </>
  }
</DropDown>
```

Comment: Mmh, this might work. I already have props with components on the drop down, it would be just another one.

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATED

Accordingly @pupeno (and he is right), the dropdown logic should be within the dropdown itself. However, we should pass a callback function in order to deal with the chosen data.

```js
class DropDown extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
  };
  
  toggleDropdown = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      open: !this.state.open,
    });
    
    const value = e.target.getAttribute('value');
    
    if ( value !== "null") {
      this.props.selectItem(value);
    }
  };
  
  render() {
    const { selectItem } = this.props;
    const { open } = this.state;
    
    return (
      <div className={open ? "drop-down open" : "drop-down"}>
        <div onClick={this.toggleDropdown} value="null">Select</div>
        <div onClick={this.toggleDropdown} value="1">Item 1</div>
        <div onClick={this.toggleDropdown} value="2">Item 2</div>
        <div onClick={this.toggleDropdown} value="3">Item 3</div>
      </div> 
    );
  }
};

class App extends React.Component {
  requestItem = (item) => {
    alert(`Request item ${item}`);
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DropDown selectItem={this.requestItem}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

```css
.drop-down {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 180px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.3s ease;
}

.open {
  height: 120px;
}

.drop-down > div {
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I don't understand this option very well. I don't want the parent to have any dropdown logic, I want the dropdowns to be self contained. Imagine a page in which we retrieve N records from the database and create N drop downs.

Comment: I @pupeno, I updated my answer to show a functional solution. I kept the dropdown logic encapsulated, and gave it a callback function. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an onChange function and call the parent function that is passed down as a prop. This will "affect the parent" as you asked.

`this.props.onChange()` or something similar.